# Объединение данных ячеек скриптом Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Имеются три колонки. Колонка А - города, колонка B - улицы. В С хотелось бы увидеть их комбинацию "Город, улица". И хотелось бы это **через скрипт** именно реализовать.

Answer (score 2):

```
function unionRanges(e) {
  var result = [];
  try {
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments[0].length; i++) {
      var row = [];
      for (var j = 0; j < arguments.length; j++) {
        if (arguments[j][i]) {
          row.push(arguments[j][i]);
        } else {
          row.push('');
        }
      }
      result.push(row.join(' '));
    }
    return result;
  } catch (err) {
    return JSON.stringify(err);
  }
}
```

Еще примеры и идеи [How to union ranges in google spreadsheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10793321/how-to-union-ranges-in-google-spreadsheets)

Но более удобным вариантом для объединения диапазонов являются операции обработки массивов `{}` и `ARRAYFORMULA()` https://plus.google.com/+AlexanderIvanov/posts/KVto7ciSVv2